# Converting binary into percentages

Tags: google-sheets

I'm using a binary system to determine whether someone showed up that date or not. `1` is "yes" `0` is "no". I am looking to turn this binary into a percentage:

[image: WA100902 question example]

```
100/5 = 20    * 3 = 60%
```

but I will need to add more dates in future and I don't want to keep having to calculate it by myself.

Is there a formula for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's better to have percentage on the left, next to the name. Otherwise, in a few months you will be scrolling way over to the right to see someone's percentage.

Use the `average` function, which takes the average of the values. And format the cell with this formula as a percentage, so that 0.6 is shown as 60%. (See Format > Number > Percent in the menu).

Example: `=average(C2:2)` is the average of all numbers in row 2, from column C to the last column (whatever it is). Put this in column B, copy it down, format as percentage and you won't need to change these formulas again.